# WebService Client Generation Error with JDK8

Tags: webservice-client, java-8, netbeans-8

I need to consume a web service in my project. I use NetBeans so I right-clicked on my project and tried to add a new "Web Service Client". Last time I checked, this was the way to create a web service client. But it resulted in an AssertionError, saying:

> java.lang.AssertionError: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jar:file:/path/to/glassfish/modules/jaxb-osgi.jar!/com/sun/tools/xjc/reader/xmlschema/bindinfo/binding.xsd; lineNumber: 52; columnNumber: 88; schema_reference: Failed to read schema document '**xjc.xsd**', because 'file' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the **accessExternalSchema** property.

The default Java platform for NetBeans was JDK8 (Oracle's official version), so when I changed my netbeans.conf file and made JDK7 (from Oracle, as well) as my default, everything worked fine. So I think the problem is with JDK8. Here is my `java -version` output:

> java version "1.8.0"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0-b132)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.0-b70, mixed mode)

For now, I'm keeping JDK7 as my default Java platform. If there is a way to make JDK8 work please share.

Comment: I experienced a problem in Eclipse that jaxb sources were not generated when using m2eclipse and jdk1.8. In the markers view I saw a similar error about  "accessExternalSchema". When I applied the chosen solution below,restarted eclipse and cleaned the project, the sources got generated!

Answer (score 432, accepted):

Well, I found the solution. (based on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/XMLConstants.html#ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA)

Create a file named `jaxp.properties` (if it doesn't exist) under `/path/to/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib` and then write this line in it:

```
javax.xml.accessExternalSchema = all
```

That's all. Enjoy JDK 8.

Comment: Worked for me but I needed to restart Netbeans for it to work.

Comment: Tried this. It didn't work for me. Using NetBeans 8.0.2, JRE 1.8.0_25, JDK 1.8.0_25, and Java EE 7. I'm running Windows 7 64bit

Comment: @Max West, Strange, it worked for me, i got the same configurations as yours except, iam running win 8.1

Comment: Works for intelliJ too.

Comment: I also had the same issue as Max West, but followed the answer provided by @Debashish Barik and it now works fine for me

Comment: Works as advertised just confirmed. Some platform details: maven = 3.3.1 JDK = 1.8.0_40 OS = OSX 10.10.3

Comment: I can confirm this solution also as working for maven build in eclipse with maven and jaxb-plugin. Can somebody explain why you don't need this property for Java7?

Comment: @DannyLo because java 7 is reaching end-of-life soon, that's why... ;)

Comment: Thanks a TON! This works for Java 1.8 but not for 1.7.

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to put the file under `/path/to/jdk1.8.0/lib` not under the further `jre` directory.

Comment: This isn't very portable. You would need to tweak a local JDK installation on a machine of every developer that tries to build the project.

Comment: Thanks bro.It worked like a charm...thanks a lot for sharing it :)

Comment: this is not working for me, the following worked:
javax.xml.accessExternalDTD = all,

Also I can set this in code and it works:
System.setProperty("javax.xml.accessExternalDTD", "all");

Comment: @Natix Agreed, see my answer for a portable solution that does not require JDK modification or global JDK flags

Comment: Is there a way to set this property in another place, if the JDK folder is read-only due to company policy ?

Comment: @SorinPostelnicu this jvm configuration can also be done in the pom.xml

Comment: Does this get added to the jenkins or nexus instance? I created the file in both and added mentioned property with no success. Here is my error. 

`Nexus Repository Manager 3.x connection failed
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 123; External DTD: Failed to read external DTD 'xhtml1-transitional.dtd', because 'http' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalDTD property.]`

Any help is tremendously appreciated.

Comment: works as explained here. Also had a JDK8, for an older project!

Comment: Why isn't this the default behavior? Why block access to https by default?

Answer (score 132):

Not an actual answer but more as a reference.

If you are using the jaxws Maven plugin and you get the same error message, add the mentioned property to the plugin configuration:

```
...
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.3</version>
  <configuration>
    <!-- Needed with JAXP 1.5 -->
    <vmArgs>
        <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
    </vmArgs>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: The `accessExternalSchema=all` value is set by default if you use later versions (like 0.12.3) of the `org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin` plugin.

Comment: The above didn't work for me. This version did: 

    <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${version.jaxws.plugin}</version>
    <configuration>
    <!-- Needed with JAXP 1.5 -->
    <vmArgs>
    <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
    </vmArgs>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>

Comment: @JonOnstott: have the latest 2.4.1 and it's not working by default. Had to add this like in the answer.

Answer (score 42):

I run ant builds within Eclipse IDE (4.4, Luna, on Windows 7 x64).  Rather than modifying the installed JRE lib or any ant scripts (I have multiple projects that include XJC in their builds), I prefer to change Eclipse Settings "External Tools Configurations" and add the following to the VM arguments for the Ant build configuration:

```
-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
```

Comment: I use wsdl2java.bat from Apache CXF. So I just inserted the JVM option into this BAT-file. It works.

Comment: I could also add, than if we include this option as ant parameter, all other includes mentioned here, are excessive. But not vice versa! So this is the best solution. +1 (of course, Maven users should do appropriate change in Maven options)

Comment: I had a similar issue when I tried to run mvn clean install , I just added this above flag and it was succesfully deployed. Thanks

Answer (score 39):

The following works for wsimport 2.2.9 included in jdk 1.8.0_66:

```
wsimport -J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all ....
```

Comment: This works for me. I tried with jdk 1.8.0_65 and that didn't work, so make sure you are using jdk 1.8.0_66 or later.

Comment: This is the correct answer when using `wsimport` directly.

Answer (score 26):

In my case adding:

```
javax.xml.accessExternalSchema = all
```

to jaxp.properties didn't work, I've to add:

```
javax.xml.accessExternalDTD = all
```

My environment is linux mint 17 and java 8 oracle.
I'll put it there as an answer for people with the same problem.

Comment: It depends whether you want to allow access to external DTD or to XML Schema (XSD). DTD is the predecessor of XML Schema. There might also be cases where you need to set both!

Answer (score 17):

I tested this for version 2.4 of artifact org.codehaus.mojo and that worked ~

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>

                <goals>
                    <goal>wsimport</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <wsdlDirectory>path/to/dir/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                </configuration>
                <id>wsimport-web-service</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
                <artifactId>webservices-api</artifactId>
                <version>${webservices-api-version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
            <vmArgs>
                <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
            </vmArgs>
            <sourceDestDir>generated-sources/jaxws-wsimport</sourceDestDir>
            <xnocompile>true</xnocompile>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <extension>true</extension>
            <sei>/</sei>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: Perhaps it is the vmArgs `-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all` that is configured in your plugin declaration.

It is discussed in Netbeans [Bug 244891](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=244891)

Answer (score 17):

Here is a hint Hint for gradle users without admin rights: add this line to your jaxb-task:

```
System.setProperty('javax.xml.accessExternalSchema', 'all')
```

it will look like this:

```
jaxb {
    System.setProperty('javax.xml.accessExternalSchema', 'all')
    xsdDir = "${project.name}/xsd"
    xjc {
        taskClassname = "com.sun.tools.xjc.XJCTask"
        args = ["-npa", "-no-header"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If you are getting this problem when converting wsdl to jave with the [cxf-codegen-plugin](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html), then you can solve it by configuring the plugin to fork and provide the additional "-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all" JVM option.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${cxf.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <fork>always</fork>
                        <additionalJvmArgs>
                            -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
                        </additionalJvmArgs>
```

Comment: thanks! all the above options do not help and yours is working for me

Answer (score 10):

I was also getting similar type of error in Eclipse during  testing  a webservice program on glassfish 4.0 web server:
`java.lang.AssertionError: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: bundle://158.0:1/com/sun/tools/xjc/reader/xmlschema/bindinfo/binding.xsd; lineNumber: 52; columnNumber: 88; schema_reference: Failed to read schema document 'xjc.xsd', because 'bundle' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.`

I have added `javax.xml.accessExternalSchema = All` in `jaxp.properties`, but doesnot work for me.

However I found a solution here below which work for me:
For GlassFish Server, I need to modify the `domain.xml` of the GlassFish, 
path :`<path>/glassfish/domains/domain1` or `domain2/config/domain.xml`) and add, `<jvm-options>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</jvm-options>`under the `<java-config>` tag

```
....
```

`<java-config>
...
 <jvm-options>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</jvm-options>
</java-config>`

...and then restart the GlassFish server

Comment: I see two instances of <java-config classpath-suffix…> in the domain.xml file. Both have sections of <jvm-options> in them. I placed the line above (with the jvm-options tags) into both sections. It still doesn't work to run the Test Web Service. I know the project is working because the handcoded client file accesses the service files and prints out the right info in the console (from the database associated with the service files).

Comment: <p>I did close the project, and the client project, exited NetBeans and waited for Glassfish to shut itself down (it shows a progress meter while it's shutting down). Then, I restarted Netbeans, reloaded the Web Services project, reloaded the Client file (it's just a Java class in a separate/regular Java Project folder). The client prints out the tables, which shows that the server and database server are working, as well as the SOAP service Web Services & EJBs. It's just not working. The accessExternalSchema setting is buried somewhere, and is not getting set properly in the new JDK.</p>

Answer (score 9):

**Enabling Access to External Schema**

You need to enable the IDE and the GlassFish Server to access external schema to parse the WSDL file of the web service. To enable access you need to modify the configuration files of the IDE and the GlassFish Server. For more details, see the FAQ How to enable parsing of WSDL with an external schema?
Configuring the IDE

To generate a web service client in the IDE from a web service or WSDL file you need to modify the IDE configuration file (netbeans.conf) to add the following switch to netbeans_default_options.

```
-J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
```

For more about locating and modifying the netbeans.conf configuration file, see Netbeans Conf FAQ.
Configuring the GlassFish Server

If you are deploying to the GlassFish Server you need to modify the configuration file of the GlassFish Server (domain.xml) to enable the server to access external schemas to parse the wsdl file and generate the test client. To enable access to external schemas, open the GlassFish configuration file (GLASSFISH_INSTALL/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml) and add the following JVM option element (in bold). You will need to restart the server for the change to take effect.

```
</java-config>
  ...
  <jvm-options>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</jvm-options>
</java-config>
```

Answer (score 7):

Create a file named `jaxp.properties` (if it doesn’t exist) under path to your "JDK version/jre/lib" and then add the following line in it.

```
javax.xml.accessExternalSchema = all
```

Comment: On MacOS:
Create the file `jaxp.properties` under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_231.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib`

Answer (score 6):

When using Maven with IntelliJ IDE you can add `-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all` to Maven setting under JVM Options for [Maven Build Tools Runner configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/maven-runner.html)

Comment: Works with Linux Mint 17.3, JDK 1.8.0.74 and Intellij IDEA 15. Thx.

Comment: Nice ! it's also work for me when I use "mvn clean install -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all" directly on terminal independently of IDE

Answer (score 6):

This works on jdk1.8.0_65

```
wsimport -J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all -keep -verbose https://your webservice url?wsdl
```

Answer (score 4):

For those using the ANT task `wsimport`, a way of passing the option as suggested by @CMFly and specified in the [documentation](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.2.10/docs/ch04.html#tools-wsimport-ant-task) is the following:

```xml
<wsimport
   <!-- ... -->
   fork="true"
  >
  <jvmarg value="-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all"/>
</wsimport>
```

Answer (score 4):

It is now fixed in 2.5 version (released in jul/17). https://github.com/mojohaus/jaxws-maven-plugin/issues/8.

For the 2.4.x versions there is a workaround (as decribed in https://github.com/mojohaus/jaxws-maven-plugin/issues/4):

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-tools</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.10</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Answer (score 3):

I used it with a regular **maven** project, and got it solved with this plugin dependency configuration for running the `xjc plugin`:

```
     <plugin>
        <!-- Needed to run the plugin xjc en Java 8 or superior -->
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>set-additional-system-properties</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>set-system-properties</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
            <properties>
                <property>
                    <name>javax.xml.accessExternalSchema</name>
                    <value>all</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>javax.xml.accessExternalDTD</name>
                    <value>all</value>
                </property>
            </properties>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: With this solution, I needed to update `jaxws-maven-plugin` to 2.5 as specified in others answers https://www.mojohaus.org/jaxws-maven-plugin/usage.html
But still, **best answer** in my case, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Another solution to address: [wiki.netbeans.org](http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWSDLExternalSchema)**

The Web Service Client wizard in the IDE parses the WSDL file when generating a web service client from a web service or WSDL file. You need to modify the IDE configuration file (netbeans.conf) to add the following switch to the netbeans_default_options. You will need to restart the IDE for the change to take effect.

```
-J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
```

When deploying to GlassFish you need to enable access to external schema to generate a test client for a web service. To enable access you need to modify the configuration file of the GlassFish Server (GLASSFISH_INSTALL/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml) and add the following JVM option element. You will need to restart the server for the change to take effect.

```
</java-config>
  ...
  <jvm-options>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</jvm-options>
</java-config>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I can not think anything else.

Answer (score 2):

I have just tried that if you use `SoapUI (5.4.x)` and use `Apache CXF` tool to generate java code, put `javax.xml.accessExternalSchema = all` in `YOUR_JDK/jre/lib/jaxp.properties` file also works.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ant you can add a jvmarg to your java calls:

```
<jvmarg value="-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all" />
```

Comment: Can you be more specific where you put this in an ant file?

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to update wsimport.sh shell script by adding the following:

The wsimport.sh is located in this directory:

jaxws-ri.2.2.28/bin

exec "$JAVA" $WSIMPORT_OPTS -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all -jar "$JAXWS_HOME/lib/jaxws-tools.jar" "$@"

Comment: I'd love to try your suggestion, but apparently jaxws-ri.2.2.28/bin is not anywhere on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Another reference:
If you are using the `maven-jaxb2-plugin`, prior to version 0.9.0, you can use the workaround described [on this issue](https://java.net/jira/browse/MAVEN_JAXB2_PLUGIN-80), in which this behaviour affected the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

NetBeans update their tutorial for JDK8 and this Issue:

[Getting Started with JAX-WS Web Services -> Enabling Access to External Schema](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/jax-ws.html#extschema)

Answer (score 0):

A very simple portable solution would be, to place the following line of code somewhere in a crucial part of your code, a part of which you are sure that it will be run (for example right in the main method):

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.accessExternalDTD", "all");
```

This sets the needed system property programmatically, without having to do tricky maven pom.xml changes (which for some reason didn't work for me).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Intellij IDEA`, in the maven tool window

[image]

select `Maven Settings` and expand the `Maven` drop down and select `Runner`.

[image]

Under the `VM Options` add `-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all`

Answer (score 0):

Using RAD 9.6 with JDK 1.8 websphere 8.5 runtime on Windows,
editing the xjc.bat as in [Generate Java gives "Failed to read external schema..." error](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/node/6507709) didn't work with me, adding/updating the jaxb.properties didn't work as well,

however I edited the wsimport as in below note

> you may modify the wsimport.bat file to specify the property directly as one of the jvm arguments like below:-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
> Our customers reported that the above solution worked for them.

as mentioned in [SAXParseException](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z000062kXrgCAE/saxparseexception-and-asserti0nerror-occur-with-error-message-the-jar-access-is-not-allowed-in-websphere-application-server-v85511-and-ibm-sdk-v80320?language=en_US), and it was the solution in my case.