# wsimport schema_reference warning due to HTTPS on XSD

Tags: java, web-services, https, wsimport, jaxp

I am running the JDK 1.8.0_51 *wsimport* from a Command Prompt on Windows 7. The WSDL URL is accessed via HTTPS:

> wsimport -keep -Xnocompile https://...?wsdl

The WSDL contains a reference to an XSD also accessed via HTTPS:

> ...schemaLocation="https://...?xsd=1"

I get this warning:

> [WARNING] schema_reference: Failed to read schema document '...?xsd=1', because 'https' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.

The tool does generate the client Java code, but I am not sure if this code is correct.

I tried to follow the solution offered in [WebService Client Generation Error with JDK8](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23011547/1408140) by creating a jaxp.properties file with javax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all and placing this file in %JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib. No effect.

I also tried to place this file in other sub-directories, such %JAVA_HOME%\lib (which is mentioned in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/XMLConstants.html#ACCESS_EXTERNAL_SCHEMA), and %JAVA_HOME%\bin, all to no avail.

So, the problem boils down to: How to instruct JAXP in the context of *wsimport* to allow the HTTPS protocol? There does not appear to be any *wsimport* command-line option to convey such a setting.

Any other suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi, did You solved this problem somehow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try adding the option `-J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all`.

Comment: This worked. The trick is to avoid any spaces between `-J` and `-D`.

Answer (score -1):

Since I asked this question, I was not able to get rid of the `wsimport` warning; I simply ignored it. While I have not observed any adverse effects, I am still not 100% convinced that the generated code is correct and optimal, since the XSD is not being read.