# wsimport schema_reference warning when trying to generate artifacts for Sabre Retrieve Itinerary API

Tags: soap, sabre, wsimport

I am trying to generate artifacts for [Sabre Retrieve Itinerary](https://developer.sabre.com/docs/soap_apis/management/itinerary/Retrieve_Itinerary/resources).

This is the script I am using:

```
wsimport -keep \
         -verbose \
         https://developer.sabre.com/sites/default/files/resources/8258/GetReservation_1.19.0.wsdl \
         -B-XautoNameResolution \
         -Xnocompile
```

However I am getting the following warning and even though Java code gets generated I am not sure if it's correct.

```
[WARNING] schema_reference: Failed to read schema document 'msg-header-2_0.xsd', because 'https' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property. 
  line 4 of https://developer.sabre.com/sites/default/files/resources/8258/GetReservation_1.19.0.wsdl#types?schema1
```

This warning is a bit weird as the WSDL contains this line:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.ebxml.org/namespaces/messageHeader" schemaLocation="msg-header-2_0.xsd"/>
```

So msg-header-2_0.xsd is referenced via http, not https.

What I have tried so far:

1. I added jaxp.properties file to my JAVAHOME/lib and JAVAHOME/jre/lib with the following content:

> javax.xml.accessExternalSchema = all

2. I added an additional option as suggested [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31996694/wsimport-schema-reference-warning-due-to-https-on-xsd):

> -J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all

But neither of those helped. My setup is as follows:

```
java -version 
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.54.0.21-CA-macosx) (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.54.0.21-CA-macosx) (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
```

Has anybody else encountered this problem or knows how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following command works for me...

```
wsimport -J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalDTD=all -J-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all -keep -verbose https://developer.sabre.com/sites/default/files/resources/8258/GetReservation_1.19.0.wsdl -Xnocompile
```