# Failed to read schema document 'xjc.xsd' - GlassFish 4

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, webserver, glassfish-4

So I started to learn some web services.
When I try to run a test from the admin web page i get this[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7L0eY.jpg):

I`m using GlassFish 4, jdk1.8.0_144, and Eclipse Oxigen.2

The console log :

```
2018-01-30T22:18:20.043+0200|Info: Invoking wsimport with http://c2kd7k72:8080/SoapTest/ProductCatalogService?WSDL
2018-01-30T22:18:20.045+0200|Info: parsing WSDL...
2018-01-30T22:18:20.062+0200|Info: [WARNING] schema_reference: Failed to read schema document 'ProductCatalogService?xsd=1', because 'http' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.
2018-01-30T22:18:20.062+0200|Info: line 4 of http://c2kd7k72:8080/SoapTest/ProductCatalogService?WSDL#types?schema1
2018-01-30T22:18:20.072+0200|Warning: StandardWrapperValve[ProductCatalog]: Servlet.service() for servlet ProductCatalog threw exception
java.lang.AssertionError: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: bundle://158.0:1/com/sun/tools/xjc/reader/xmlschema/bindinfo/binding.xsd; lineNumber: 52; columnNumber: 88; schema_reference: Failed to read schema document 'xjc.xsd', because 'bundle' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.
```

I have tried different solutions found on stackoverflow like changing the domian.xml from the "Java\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\config" with :

-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all , but still no luck. 
Did some one have any ideea how to resolve this ? Thank you in advance.

EDIT: [domain.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djAdW.jpg) cfg file

EDIT2: Tried with [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S18ZV.jpg) as well:

Comment: did u see this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011547/webservice-client-generation-error-with-jdk8

Comment: Add the fragment where you reference xjc.xsd please.

Comment: I have updated my post with a screenshot of my domain config file . Any suggestions ?