# How do I resolve a schema parse exception with Ant?

Tags: java, ant, xjc

I have an ant `build.xml` file which contains xjc targets.

Apparently the build process works with Ant 1.7.1, but any newer version results in build failure. I'm using the following:

- ANT 1.9.7
- Java JDK 1.8.0_171

The exact text of the error message is:

> build.xml:96: java.lang.AssertionError: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: jar:file:*path*/lib/jaxb-xjc.jar!/com/sun/tools/xjc/reader/xmlschema/bindinfo/binding.xsd; lineNumber: 52; columnNumber: 88; schema_reference: Failed to read schema document 'xjc.xsd', because 'file' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.

So, I researched this, and came up with the idea from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23011547/webservice-client-generation-error-with-jdk8) that I needed to specify a command-line argument for the JVM, so I added one at the appropriate location in the `build.xml` file:

```
<arg value="-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all" />
```

Now, I'm getting a different error, apparently caused by this addition:

> build.xml:96: unrecognized parameter -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all

How do I resolve the initial error so my build doesn't fail with this issue?

Comment: Please refer this answer for more clarification.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23012746/5667202

Answer (score 2):

Create a file called `jaxp.properties` and in it include the following content `javax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all`.

Place this file in your Java directory's `jre/lib` folder.